# Using QGIS vs. SVG to export with area names?

Tags: shapefile, export, area, svg, geonames

Is there the possibility of exporting a SVG files (from shapefile) which retains the area names?

Basically any closed path should have the original name attributed to shapefiles. But not only. I would also have individual geoid points appointed in the same way. Even so unique, "point_AREANAME", while the area should be called simply "AREANAME".

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

The [SimpleSvg](https://www.duif.net/qgis/simplesvg/) plugin (as described in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66041/how-to-convert-shapefile-to-svg-keeping-internal-data/66067#66067)) passes through some of the shapefile's attributes. It only works with Old Symbology layers, and may produce SVG that's specific to the [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) drawing program.