# Exporting attribute table to Excel from QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, csv, excel

I have seen all the questions for how to export an attribute table to Excel from QGIS, and I try all the answers like copy paste, CSV (in fact this I do not know where to find), but none seems to be the right answer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What method have you tried for copy-paste into Excel?

Comment: Siple copy-paste. Select all the feature, copy, open excel, select more then my feature cloumns, rows and paste. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, select-all then copy, but don't try to select the range of cells within Excel, paste into a single cell. What error did you get?

Comment: Many rows with a long number. In some cells the information is missing. Looks like it is not the right way? Shuold have another way that give you the column and the rows like they are in your attribute table.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**QGIS v3.x**

Right click on the layer in the Table of Contents (aka. legend or layer tree) and open the `Save As...` dialog.

Once there, click on the `Format` option list and choose `MS Office Open XML spreadsheet [XLSX]`.

Note that you also have an option for Libre Office files: `Open Document spreadsheet [ODS]`.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER (no longer valid):

1. Install the [XY Tools plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/) by Richard Duivenvoorde.
2. Select a vector file from the ToC (that is, make it active).
3. Go to `Vector->XY tools->Save attribute table as Excel file`.

[image]

*You would need the Python library xlw installed for doing so.*

Comment: Yes, but I want it for free. To get XYtools you need to pay. Is there any other way?

Comment: @PoPo You don't need to pay for using XY tools plugin, I myself use it. The author suggests you to donate 5€ if you use the plugin, but it's up to you to donate.

Comment: Can you give me a link, please?

Comment: @PoPo You can download the plugin from [here](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/version/0.3.5/download/) or simply go to `Plugins->Manage and Install plugins` and search for xytools.

Comment: Yes now I have that,but look the problem that it have
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\xytools.py", line 301, in excelSave
    xlw.writeAttributeRow(rowNr, values)
  File "C:.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\providers\excel.py", line 51, in writeAttributeRow
    cell = str(cell)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: ordinal not in range(128)
Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
QGIS version:
2.2.0-Valmiera Valmiera, c3a2817

Comment: @PoPo Can you try the previous version of the plugin? You can download it from [here](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/version/0.3.4/download/).

Comment: It not allow me to choose the previous version, but download the lastes verison.

Comment: Might be this issue with non-ASCII-caharcters as field values: https://github.com/rduivenvoorde/xytools/issues/3

Comment: @PoPo You can download it from the last link I gave you, delete your current `xytools` folder in `USER/.qgis2/python/plugins/`. Then extract the downloaded zip into that location. Restart QGIS and you're done. I see there were modifications to the file `excel.py` in the latest version, and I've used the previous one without problems.

Comment: @gcarrillo Thank you. Yes, now it's working. Thank you a lot.

Comment: When I installed the XY Tools I found that some python library was missing from my install (osx). Not sure what it was. I voted for the CSV answer by AndreJ because ultimately that's what I wanted -- this question came up when I searched for "qgis export attribute csv". Also, because CSV is more useful than an "Excel file" because it is natively supported by any reputable spreadsheet program, including basic text editors.

Comment: It's up to you. I still read in the title "How to export attribute table to **Excel** from QGIS?".

Comment: This answer is a little outdated, I found [the answer below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317775/145981) to be more current.

Answer (score 29):

To get a csv file of the attribute table, rightclick on the layer in the legend, select `Save As ...`, and change the file format from shapefile to CSV.

You might need to change the separator from comma to semicolon in a text editor if Excel does not like the default separator.

Comment: Yes I try to do that but I din't find csv format file in my drop-down menu. Can you show an image, please.

Comment: "Comma Separated Value [CSV]" third option from the top.

Comment: Thanks, but now it's not working. I cann't open the file in Excel.

Comment: This answer is more robust, because it works for other generic spreadsheet programs as well. CSV is easily opened in Excel through the Import Text wizard. You just need to specify "Text (CSV)" in the format

Answer (score 14):

In QGIS versions 3 and above, the easiest way to export an attribute table is to:

1. Right-click the attribute layer in the layers menu
2. Select `Export` and `Save features as...`
3. At the top of the program window, select `Comma Separated Value [CSV]` in the `format` drop-down menu
4. Type a file name for the file to be saved
5. Click the three-dot button <kbd>...</kbd> next to the file name to choose a path to where the file should be saved
6. Uncheck any fields you do not want in your resulting file
7. Optionally (probably) uncheck the `add saved file to map` at the bottom of the window so that the file does not get added to your project as a data layer
8. Click the green check mark, <kbd>Ok</kbd> button

Comment: This is the most recent and accurate answer for the more recent versions of QGIS. I'm using 3.4.11-Madeira and this worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

There's also the [MMQGIS Plugin](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) which, when downloaded and installed from the toolbar (*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...*), has the tool:

*MMQGIS > Import/Export > Attributes Export to CSV File*

[image: MMQGIS Attributes Export to CSV File]

Answer (score 4):

1. Select rows
2. Copy selected rows to clipboard
3. Paste in Excel

[image]

Comment: This is my preferred method.  I found it a bit annoying that the geometry field was copied  as well until I discovered one can go to Settings - Data sources  and change the Copy features dropdown to plain text, no geometry.  I also find the fields & rows can be oddly sized for word wrapping in Excel, but if I expand the column width to some overly large size, I can then use the autofit fields and rows options in Excel to get a nice looking table.

Comment: Most helpful.  Here is what worked after many failures with a notice no copy was made.  As johns suggested, I went to Settings - Data sources, and changed to plain text, no geometry.  Then, instead of using Control+A to select the 16 features I had filtered to using an expression to filter out from about 20,000 features to the 16 I needed, I selected each row one at a time holding down the Control key (when I used Control + A to select all of the 16 features showing, I believe it tried to copy all 20,000+ features in the layer (not visible to me), which also happened with the export method).

Comment: **Keep in mind : this approach will also copy the hidden column "wkt_geom" with geometry!**

Answer (score 4):

From QGIS 3.18 ([see the Changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-new-export-to-spreadsheet-algorithm)), you can use the ["Export to spreadsheet"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html#export-to-spreadsheet) algorithm available in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

It enables to export one or more layers in multiple sheets, to overwrite or append them to existing files. Output formats supported are Excel XLSX and Open Document Spreadsheet (*'.ods'*)

Fine for exporting full layers, otherwise, keep using already mentioned methods in other answers when you need to export selected features to spreadsheet

[image: Export to spreadsheet screen capture]

Comment: Should be using this instead of other ways.

Comment: Where is this found?  I'm looking all through the processing toolbox with QGIS 3.18 but I cannot see how to bring this screen up!

Comment: Ah I've found it but it's available from QGIS 3.20 on.

Comment: According to the release notes, from 3.18 not 3.20 https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/#feature-new-export-to-spreadsheet-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Export the layer as a shapefile, find the shapefile on your PC.
Copy/Rename the filename of the DBF part of the shapefile exportes to be 8 or under characters if it's not. (OLD MS DOS FILENAME ISSUE).
Then, drag-drop the DBF right into Excel.

Save as XLS.

The copy paste method right form QGIS made text/character returns in a blob reset to the next row and cause data problems in excel.

Answer (score 1):

X/Y tools is regrettably no longer available in QGIS 3.x. There is another way how to export the attribute table to Excel, without any trouble concerning text encoding, column names and fields containing special characters in foreign languages like e.g. Vietnamese,. However, your input file should be in UTF-8 encoded:

1. Right click on the shp file, Export, save features as Open Document Spreadsheet (ODS.
2. Open the ODS file with LibreOffice or MS Excel.
3. Save as Excel file (xls or xlsx)