# XyTools QGIS plugin for attribute export

Tags: qgis, excel, ascii

I want to export an attribute table to Excel. I see XyTools is used for that (is there another plugin?). Since I installed QGIS from OSGeo4W, I have the required library. However, when I tell XyTools to export the table, I get the following Python error message: ***UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)*** because my table contains nonASCII characters, which is not that unusual, especially for foreign languages. My question is: Is there a fix or workaround this issue or another plugin to export an attribute table to Excel?

[image: the error message]

Comment: See here [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135801/how-to-export-attribute-table-to-excel-from-qgis) for additional information

Answer (score 2):

You can use Save As from the layer popup menu to save attribute table to a CSV file which can be opened by Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If your layer is a shapefile, you can also open the *.dbf file with Excel and save it as *.xls format.

Comment: Yes, I know about saving to CSV file and opening a DBF. I was looking for a more direct way, and frankly, can't believe XY Tools can be so limited not to handle Unicode :o