# How to export training area information?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification, landsat-8

I did a supervised classification of a whole Landsat 8 image with 700 Rois (training areas) with the Semi Automatic Classification Plugin. I want to export the class names, the coordinates and the pixel size from the training areas.Furthermore I need spectral information from each pixel from all bands 2-7. I want to produce a excel file with all mentioned values.  The final data shall be used with SVM (Support Vector Machine) to improve my classification. I don't know how to export all of the values.

Comment: Are you just trying to export to excel? If so, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135801/how-to-export-attribute-table-to-excel-from-qgis.  If not, can you explain a little more what it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want to use each pixel as a point in a diagram and after that cluster them to groups. For example a diagram with x=band1 y =band2 with all pixels in it. Furthermore I want to create a thresold in the end to improve the classification. I want to kick out the spectral signatures which are not appropriate, because I need a classification with high accuracy.