# Getting coordinates from random points in polygon and sync it with shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, point-creation

In QGIS I have a shapefile that contains a polygon of administrative boundaries in a country. I need to add six random points inside the polygon.

Can i get the coordinates from random points feature and sync it with my polygons?

Ex: I have US administrative boundaries shapefile that contains `"country_name"` and `"state_name"`. Then, i generate six random points for every states. Afterward, i want an exported *.xlsx* file which contains `"country_name"`, `"state_name"`, `"lat_long_1"`, `"lat_long_2"`, etc. accordance with its state.

What should i do?

Comment: (1) "Random points inside polygons" *(sampling strategy: count)* (2) "Join attributes by location" (3) "Add X/Y fields to layer" (4) Export as a CSV

Comment: It works, thank you! @Taras

Comment: Of course you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'gadm40_SVN_1'*. Data was taken from https://gadm.org/download_country.html.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Random points inside polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#random-points-inside-polygons) geoalgorithm with *'Points count'* as a sampling strategy.

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** Use the ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) tool to get desired fields for a point layer from the polygon layer. *'Are within'* is a suitable geometric predicate for this stage. [The spatial index](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#create-spatial-index) can be additionally used to improve the performance over big data sets.

[image: step2]

**Step 3.** Make use of the ["Add X/Y fields to layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-x-y-fields-to-layer) geoalgorithm. I used the [EPSG:3794](https://epsg.org/crs_3794/Slovenia-1996-Slovene-National-Grid.html) which is a [Projected coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projected_coordinate_system).

[image: step3]

**Step 4.** Finally, export the layer in a preferred output format via `right-mouse click > Export > Save Feature As`. For Excel, the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format can be suitable. Otherwise, I suggest paying attention to this article: [Exporting attribute table to Excel from QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135801/exporting-attribute-table-to-excel-from-qgis).